# Trouble finding the expected value of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

Suppose that we have a procedure `A` that we run once and it returns as a result either `success` or `failure`. Our goal is to run `A` as many times as needed in order to receive `success`. Given that the probability of a `success` is $\geq \frac{1}{2}$ we would like to find what is the expected number of times that we will have to run the procedure before getting a `success` result.

We have

$Pr[A = success] \geq \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow Pr[A = failure] \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Now the question can be transformed to, what is the expected number of failures that we will get before getting a success?

$Pr[\texttt{get i failures}] \leq \frac{1}{2^{i}}$

By applying the expectation as defined on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)  we get:

$E[\#failures] \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\inf} i\frac{1}{2^{i}} = 2$

however I can not understand why my professor during the lecture ignored the $i$ term in that summation, so he says that the answer should be $\sum_{i=1}^{\inf} \frac{1}{2^{i}} = 1$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to diagnose on little information. By your calculation, the expected number of **failures** before the first success is $\left(\sum_1^\infty \frac{i}{2^i}\right)-1$, which gives your instructor's inequality. Another way is to use the fact that the expectation of a non-negative integer-valued rv $X$ is $\sum_1^\infty \Pr(X\ge i)$.

Comment: why do we have a -1 after the summation?

Comment: It is the distinction between the number of **trials** until the first success (your sum) and the number of **failures** before the first success, which is one less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of **failures** before the first success. Then $X$ takes on only non-negative integer values. For such a random variable $X$, we have
$$E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \Pr(X\ge i).$$
For a proof, please [see Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Discrete_distribution_taking_only_non-negative_integer_values)

If the probability of failure is $q$, then $\Pr(X\ge i)=q^i$. In our case $q\le 1/2$, so 
$$E[X]=\frac{q}{1-q}\le 1.$$

One can also get to the expected value of the number of failures before the first success by using your calculation. The expected number of **failures** before the first success is one less than the number of **trials** until the first success. So to estimate the mean number of failures, subtract $1$ from the mean number of trials. Your sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i}{2^i}$ calculated an upper bound on the expected number of trials.